# Error code 2500 when requesting facebook picture

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions

I am using the social framework and the accounts framework to access facebook from my app. In one line of code I do:

```
NSURL *meInfo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
```

Which is successful. I get a json object with me data which I can then use in my app. Confusingly, in the very next block of code, I do this:

```
NSURL *meInfoPic = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture"];
```

And it fails with:

```
error =     {
        code = 2500;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

My access token is obviously valid, so I am not sure what is going on. The permissions I am using for both are "publish_stream".  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was using /me/ in the picture request URL. Once I replaced that with the user id for the logged in user I got further. So to be clear, I needed to do this:

```
NSURL *meInfoPic = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/picture"];
```

Comment: i do not know how you got it working. But you should have asked for about_me permissions to get the picture.